# Visual table editor for linux

Tags: tables, editors

Is there any visual LaTeX-table editor for linux? I want something where I can load existing LaTeX-tables, modify them and save it in LaTeX.

Comment: Have tried [LyX](http://http://www.lyx.org/)?

Comment: [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) in Emacs is really a great way of doing this, easy export, edit, etc. For table editing see: [Org mode table](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html#Tables)

Comment: @zeroth Thanks after your comment I tried Org-mode to edit LaTeX tables. Now I have some more questions on this, do you think, that tex.stackexchange ist a good place to do so, or which stackexchange site seems to be most appropriate to you?

Comment: @student I do not think that there are any SE sites that will fulfil that, however the org-mode mailing list is highly active, and they will very fast give you an answer! Actually I have often craved for org-mode to be situated on SE. It is truly a magnificent package.

Answer (score 3):

The first three are probably your best bet for existing latex tables. Using emacs table editing mode is probably the best choice going forward if you are familiar with emacs...

- Lyx [1](http://http//www.lyx.org/)
- Kile [2](http://www.kde.org/)
- Texmacs [3](http://www.texmacs.org/)
- Emacs Table Editing Mode -> Org-export or Pandoc -> Latex [4](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode)

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some more details on option 4? How to use Org-export, howto Pandoc in this case? Is it possible to convert the table in place (i.e. without working with a temporary file, just replace the latex table by an easy editable emacs table and back)?

Comment: http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2008/07/quickly-creating-latex-tables-in-emacs.html

This takes out the org-export/pandoc middle step...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the editor but the following trick works. Use something like **`sed`** to surgically cut existing LaTeX table out of your document and pipe it into the temporary file. Then you can use [Siag](http://siag.nu/) to open your table as a 
comma-separated values file (CSV) specifying **`&`** as a field separator. You can edit then your table. You can save it in the same format and upload into the document using **`sed`**. It is probably interesting for you to know that Siag can export a valid LaTeX table code for an already existing CSV or even some other formats.

Comment: Hm. That looks promising. Do you think it is possible to connect this to emacs. I.e. if you are on a tabular environment, run a emacs command, which pipes the table through `sed` to Siag and also the other way around from Siag directly to my emacs-buffer?

Comment: Well, this tricks is actually not necessary for LaTeX. `pgfplotstable`, `datatools` and some other LaTeX packages supports csv and similar input formats.

Comment: @student I have never tried as I am vi guy but both Siag and Emacs are written in Lisp so that should not be very hard to do with minimal knowledge of Lisp.